# A singular variant of the OEIS sequence A349576

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, gcd-and-lcm

I refer to a previous [post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344652/investigating-the-recurrence-relation-x-n1-fracx-nx-n-1x-n-x) in which it is defined the recurrence relation (now OEIS sequences [A349576](https://oeis.org/A349576) and [A349982](https://oeis.org/A349982))
$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n} + x_{n-1}}{(x_{n},x_{n-1})} + c\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
where $(x_{n},x_{n-1})$ is the gcd of $x_{n}$ and $x_{n-1}$.

This recurrence relation often generates periodic sequences with periods depending on the value of the integer constant $c$.

I wondered what dynamics I would have obtained by eliminating the dependence on such constant. One of the most interesting behaviors is shown by the following relation
$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n} + x_{n-1}}{(x_{n},x_{n-1})} + (x_{n},x_{n-1})\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$
One might expect that the character (periodic or non-periodic) of the sequences generated by relation (2) depends on the choice of the initial conditions $x_0$ and $x_1$. But things are a little different.

I made some numerical experiments. The following screenshot shows the results obtained.

The image consists of a $21$ x $21$ matrix $T$ in which:

- $x_0$ is the row index;
- $x_1$ is the column index;
- $t_{\,x_0,\,x_1}$ represents the period of the sequence generated by the recurrence relation $(2)$ starting with the initial conditions $x_0,\,x_1$ (the symbol "+" stands for a probably non-periodic sequence).

[image]

Up to $21$ x $21$ only $3$ possible periods appear:

- $2901$, $\,x_n=x_{n+2901}\,$ for $\,n \ge 278$, with a peak value of $2269429312765395470820$ $(\sim 2.27\cdot 10^{21})$

[image]

- $155$, with a peak value of $513582$ (e.g. $x_0=2,x_1=19$)

[image]

- $3$, with a peak value of $60$ (e.g. the pair $x_0=13,x_1=18$ generates the sequence $13,18,32,27,60,32,27,60,32,...$).

Will different values appear for the period by extending the search scope?

And why do the three indicated values ($2901, 155, 3$) appear and not others?

---

**Edit**

Other three period lengths have been found:

- $9\,$ (see Peter's comment);
- $53\,$ ($x_0=70,x_1=207$);
- $84\,$ ($x_0=38,x_1=200$).

Comment: Why should the matrix be symmetrical? Here is a counterexample: $1,2,4,5,10,8,11,...$ and $2,1,4,6,7,14,10,...$

Comment: You are right !

Comment: $(50/57)$ and ($58/85)$ lead to a sequence with period length $9$

Comment: Please check $(2/5)$ again! I get a $155$-period here.

Comment: Yes, correct. $(2/5)$ generates a sequence with period length equal to $155$. Thanks.